# Emulator toolbar 3dot emulator settings menu missing in Android Studio 4.x emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Emulator toolbar 3dot emulator settings menu missing in Android Studio 4.x emulator

In Android Studio 3.x, there used to be a 3dot menu which takes the developer to the emulator settings as seen here -

[image]

However, this ... (3dot settings button) is missing in the Android Studio 4.x version of the emulator as seen here -

[image]

How does one get to the 3dot settings of the emulator in Android Studio 4.x ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [limitations mentioned in the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations):

> Currently, you can't use the emulator's extended controls when it's
> running in a tool window. If your development workflow depends heavily
> on the extended controls, continue to use the Android Emulator as a
> standalone application.

You can go back to using it as a standalone application by:

1. Click File > Settings > Tools > Emulator
2. Deselect "Launch in a tool window"

Answer (score 0):

You can also click F1 on emulator to get those settings